Instagram api get tagged user
I'm tring to get tagged user in post.
Currently I'm fetching user post using Business Discovery and some of the post data is possible to fetch.
But for tagged user no information is post.
Is there way or endpoint that I'm just overlooking? or just simply not possible with Business Discovery?
Also if it not possible with Business Discovery I would like to know if there is any other way to do it.
